# Integrating 2-form and change of variables question

Tags: integration, differential-forms

There's a nice quote online that says:

> "The whole point of differential forms is that integration of forms is
>   designed to work consistently with the change of variables formula. Or
>   another way to think of it, is that the change of variables formula is
>   baked into the definition of differential forms."

So I'm trying to understand the integral$$\intop_{M}\omega=\intop_{D}\omega\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial v}\right)du\,dv$$in terms of the change of variables formula that I've found in Schulz's *A Practical Introduction to Differential Forms*. Have I got this right?

A 2-form $\omega=dx\wedge dy$ acts on a couple of tangent vectors as$$\left(dx\wedge dy\right)\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial v}\right)=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{array}\right|.$$

And, from the change of variable formula$$dx\wedge dy=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{array}\right|\,du\wedge dv.$$

Is it then OK to say (hopefully, it is. It just seems too simple)?$$\omega=\omega\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial v}\right)\,du\wedge dv,$$ and integrate this to get my integral (but without the wedge for some reason)?

**Possible lightbulb moment?** Is my integral the general case of the red boxed equation (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Integration_over_chains) here?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On $\mathbb{R}^n$, given an $n$-form $\omega = f dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ on $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, one *defines*
$$\int_U \omega = \int_U f,$$
i.e. the integral is defined by integrating "without the wedge," using the standard Riemann integral on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Think of it this way: $dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n$ represents the standard infinitesimal volume on $\mathbb{R}^n$, since it is translation-invariant. So integrating with respect to it is integrating with respect to the usual volume form, which is also what Riemann integration does.

Then given a general $n$-manifold $M$ and an $n$-form $\omega$ supported on a coordinate patch $U \subseteq M$, one takes coordinates $\mathbf{x}: D \to U$ 
and defines
$$ \int_U \omega = \int_D \mathbf{x}^\ast \omega.$$

---

**Change-of-coordinates**

Let me address the quote you gave. The magic of this definition is that if $U$ and $V$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha: U \to V$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, then for an n-form $\omega$ on $V$,
$$ \int_V \omega = \int_U \alpha^\ast \omega.$$
This implies the definition I gave above for integrating on the manifold $M$ doesn't depend on coordinates.
Let's check this: the pullback of $dx_i$ under $\alpha$ is
$$ \alpha^\ast dx_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \alpha_i}{\partial x_j} dx_j,$$
so
$$ \alpha^\ast (dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n) = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \alpha_1}{\partial x_j} dx_j\right) \wedge \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \alpha_2}{\partial x_j} dx_j\right) \wedge \cdots \wedge \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial \alpha_n}{\partial x_j}dx_j\right) \\
= \det(D\alpha) dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_n,$$
and our desired formula reduces to the change-of-variables
$$ \int_V f= \int_U (f \circ \alpha) \det(D\alpha) $$
since $\alpha$ preserves orientation, so $\det(D\alpha) > 0$.

---

**Red-boxed formula**

The red-boxed formula is exactly the pullback of $\omega$ in local coordinates, if $M$ is an $n$-manifold inside $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some large $N$, and we express $\omega$ in terms of differential forms on $\mathbb{R}^N$. So, it agrees with the definition I gave above.